# Add DLL to NetBeans Project

Tags: java, dll, netbeans, import

I want to add dll file into my project. But i don't know where and how to add my dll in NetBeans anyone please help me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it may help you see the example >>>

http://wiki.netbeans.org/SlickSet

Comment: @moon Thanks for your link. I got the answer from this link. Very thanks.

Comment: @moon I read your page. I am using Netbeans 7.3 and Java 1.7_25. I copied my dll to the working directory - the same level as build/, dist/, nbproject/ When I build the jar and open it, I do not find the dll.